# Access denied error from Web.API controller and DirectoryInfo

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, directoryinfo

I have a virtual directory configured on my IIS server, pointing to a UNC network location - "\\esdata\userdata".  When I set this up I set a specific user in IIS config, and I know this user has full permissions on this directory.

Now in my Web.API controller, I am looking for a specific subdirectory in that virtual directory- say johndoe (so \\esdata\userdata\johndoe).  I can create my DirectoryInfo object okay, and the path it shows is exactly the right one.  But if I call GetDirectories() on that directory info, I get an Access Denied exception- even though there are definitely subdirectories and even though the user IIS is using to access that directory has full rights.

So first, is this a limitation of GetDirectories()?  I have read it has some issues.  What can I do to work around this, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem and fixed it.  Bottom line was that I had to configure the default ApplicationPool to use the identity of my authorized user, following the docs [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

I think what gave me trouble is that I had this directory mapped as a Virtual Directory in IIS, and mapped it as that same user.  Apparently this doesn't give the permissions to access that info the way I thought it would.  Probably not a great idea to change the application pool identity, but for an intranet based site it will get me where I want to go :)